# MySql unique id for several records

Tags: mysql, transactions

I use one table withe some casual columns such as id, name, email, etc...also I'm inserting a variable numbers of records in each transaction, to be much efficient I need to have one unique id lets call it transaction id, that would be the same for each group of data which are inserted in one transaction, should be increment. What is the best approach for doing that? 
I was thought to use

```
select max(transaction_id) from users
```

and increment that value on server side, but that seams like old fashion solution.

Comment: Don't do this max() trick unless you never have more than one connection to your mySQL server.  If you do you'll get duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

### Add new table with auto_increment column

You can create new table with [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) column. So you'll be able to generate unique integers in thread safe way. It'll work like this:

```
DB::insert_into_transaction_table()
transaction_id = DB::mysql_last_insert_id() ## this is integer value
for each record:
    DB::insert_into_table(transaction_id, ...other parameters...)
```

And you don't require mysql transactions for this.

### Generate unique string on server side before inserting

You can generate unique id (for example [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)) on server side and use it for all records inserting. But your transaction_id field should be long enough to store values generated this way (some `char(...)` type). It'll work like this:

```
transaction_id = new_GUID() ## this is usually a string value
for each record:
    DB::insert_into_table(transaction_id, ...other parameters...)
```

Comment: This will result in an ID that is unique to *each* insert. I don't think this is what he means, he wants to use the same ID for multiple records but have a unique one per *batch* or *group* of inserts.

Comment: I suggest you to create a separate table for this. It can have only a single column. And you'll need transactions too. There is no sequences in mysql so far.

Comment: I've updated unswer with this idea. And added variant without new table

Answer (score 2):

You could have another table `usergroups` with an auto-incrementing primary key, you first insert a record there (maybe including some other useful information about the group). Then get the group's unique id generated during this last insert using `mysql_insert_id()`, and use that as the `groupid` for your inserts into the first table.

This way you're still using MySQL's auto-numbering which guarantees you a unique `groupid`. Doing `select max(transaction_id) from users` and incrementing this isn't safe, since it's non-atomic (another thread may have read the same `max(transaction_id)` before you've had a change to increment it, and will start inserting records with a conflicting `groupid`).

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but if you read my post carefully I was mentioned that I want to avoid using a some additional tables(you write to use usergroups table) for the second paragraph yes I'm know that isn't a safest way. Some db's have own generators included in them and that could be used here, some simulation of that, but not so sure.

Comment: You didn't specify that you don't want additional tables. But if that's not an option, I think the solution you had - although unsafe (unless you do the select and all inserts in one transation, you'll need an InnoDB table for that) and maybe a bit cumbersome - is the best you can do. I know postgresql has auto-incrementing generators (which are also used for the unique ids) that you could call, but I don't think MySQL has something similar...

Comment: In MySQL, you're making a serious design mistake by avoiding the extra table.  If you were in Oracle, you could use a SEQUENCE object, but a table with an autoincrement primary key is the way MySQL does this.  Sorry to be blunt.  I have scorch marks on me from doing this.